# Same query giving different number of results in mysql workbench and nodejs against the same query

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-workbench

I have a query like this that I can run from mysql workbench:

```
Select distinct  partNumber from orders 
inner join orderDetail on orders.orderID = orderDetail.orderID
inner join parts on orderDetail.partID = parts.partID
where orderType = 'new' and posted is false and (coalesce(qtyShipped,0) < qtyOrdered) 
order by orderDate desc
```

This only returns 1 partNumber

But I am also running the same query in Nodejs:

```
rows = await pool.query(`Select distinct  partNumber from orders 
                inner join orderDetail on orders.orderID = orderDetail.orderID
                inner join parts on orderDetail.partID = parts.partID
                where orderType = 'new' and posted is false and (coalesce(qtyShipped,0) < qtyOrdered) order by orderDate desc`)
```

but this returns 2 records or two partNumber.

I do not understand how the same query can return different results against the same database.

Comment: Could give us data to test your output, for me your query is ok, bur you should present tabels and data, and wated outcome with that data

Comment: Are you absolutely sure they're connecting to the same DB?